# Difference b/w Create table r&<VAR> and &<VAR>

Tags: sas

I was asked to look into a SAS code today and was wondering what each of these meant. This the first time i am looking into a SAS code, so it might be a basic question. I checked the docs (and google), but didn't find the right answer.

create table **r&MAC** as

create table **&MAC** as

The full code snippet

```
create table r&MAC as
    select distinct
      <COL LIST> 
    from all;
```

and

```
create table &MAC as
    select *
    from r&MAC;
```

Any idea what the r&MAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` is a trigger to the SAS Macro language that you want to reference a macro variable.  So `&MAC` will be replaced by the value of the macro variable named MAC.  So if you set MAC to `table1`

```
%let mac=table1;
```

then run this statement:

```
create table &MAC as
    select *
    from r&MAC;
```

The SAS Macro language processor will convert that to this SAS code that will then run.

```
create table table1 as
    select *
    from rtable1;
```

Comment: Got it. The "r" in itself is not a keyword, which i thought had a special meaning. So, its just a letter concatenated to the string - Is this right?

Comment: Yes.  The programmer needed to have two table names so to make a second one they added an R in the front.